# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 264

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 264, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
```

My Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
...
private static ArrayList<String[]> Arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
...
Arr.add(264, new String[] {"title","description","icon"});
Arr.add(268, new String[] {"title2","description2","icon2"});
Arr.add(1222, new String[] {"title3","description3","icon3"});
```

I need to add another string array with its own key

Comment: What is the question? Why is it happening? How to solve it? Design issue?

Comment: If you're trying to do a sparse Integer to String[], you might consider using a Map<Integer,String[]> instead of a List<String[]> ?

Comment: yeah if use private static HashMap<Integer, String[]> arr = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>(); is OK! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a specific index unless the list is at least that big already.

This line:

```
Arr.add(264, new String[] {"title","description","icon"});
```

will only work if the list has at least 264 elements already (as the [javadoc clearly states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29), should you decide to read it).

Comment: How do I create array self key without 1, 2, 3 but, for example 22, 55, 784

Comment: @PaterSVK - you should probably be using a Map if you want to use arbitrary keys.